# How's a temporary implemented in C++?

Tags: c++, temporary

In the following `'a'` is a temporary.

```
cout << 'a';
```

It isn't restored in the data section (`const/static` does) and shouldn't be in the stack (local variable does). Where is it?

**UPDATE**

Are `non-lvalue` and `rvalue` the same thing?

Comment: But `'a'` is a character literal, not a temporary.  Real temporaries will be on the stack.

Comment: @QuantumMechanic ,so `'a'` is in the data section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have a really horrible compiler or machine architecture, `'a'` is not stored as data anywhere. It's an immediate operand in the asm, e.g.

```
mov $0x97, %eax
```

Comment: @R..,what if `cout << "abc"`?If that's still not a temporary,can you give one example?

Comment: oh,I see `b * c` is a temporary,where `b`,`c`  are variables.

Comment: It's not a temporary. It's a string literal. It will be assigned a fixed address (usually in the "text" (code) or read-only data segment) and the absolute or relative address of the string will be emitted in the asm to access it.

Comment: @cpuer: I'm not sure if or where to term "temporary" is defined, but I suspect it only applies to objects of `class` type where an actual object undergoes construction and destruction.

Comment: @R..,this term is from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171630/why-doesnt-operator-overloading-for-pointers-work/6171694#6171694

Comment: Ben's use of "temporary" there seems to be a casual way of saying "non-lvalue expression".

Comment: @R..,does `non-lvalue` equal to `rvalue`?

Comment: Does non-square mean the same thing as rectangle? :-)

Comment: @R.. ,what can it be if it's neither `lvalue` nor `rvalue`? :)

Comment: I'm not sure about C++, but in C, "rvalue" appears only in a footnote under 6.3.2.1 as a common name for "value of an expression". Similar to the relationship between rectangle and square, some rvalues are also lvalues, and perhaps all lvalues are rvalues, but I would be hesitant to claim this since I'm not familiar with the formal definition of "rvalue" in C++ (if there even is one).

Answer (score 2):

Inline with the code, usually; most modern CPUs have a "move immediate" (pedantically, PC-relative) instruction, although some older CPUs could only move from specified memory addresses (which is why Fortran was written with that assumption, resulting in constants having to actually be allocated memory).

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the operand of one of the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

See these questions:

- [where are literals stored in statement like this if var x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715034/where-are-literals-stored-in-statement-like-this-if-var-x)
- [C String literals: Where do they go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589949/c-string-literals-where-do-they-go)

Answer (score 0):

Where this will be stored depends on your compiler and your architecture.  `'a'` is generally an 8-bit quantity with the value 97.  Depending on the calling convention of your particular architecture, it will either be pushed on the stack or moved into a register just before the procedure `operator<<(ostream&, char)` is called.  However, this has nothing to do with storing `'a'` in the current scope, but setting the value of the `char`-type parameter in the callee; `'a'` is never stored in the current scope.  This can be done in one or two assembly instructions on most architectures and doesn't require storage in the static segment, heap or stack (unless parameters are passed on the stack) -- just a few bits in an instruction or two.

For example:

IA-32:

```
    pushl $0x61
    pushl ...     # address of cout
    call  ...     # address of operator<<(ostream&, char)
```

MIPS-32:

```
    addiu $a0, $zero, 0x61
    addiu $a1, $zero, ...  # address of cout
    jal   ...              # address of operator<<(ostream&, char)
```